# Is $x\in\emptyset$ defined?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We know, $A\cup B=\{x:x\in A\lor x\in B\}$

In this definition, however if A or B is empty or both A and B are empty, we are getting the term $x\in \emptyset$
This poses the problem of defining that term, which I tried by saying that if $x\in \emptyset$ then $x=null$. But, it just doesn't work because then I am just allowing x as a variable to have a 'null state' which means if $x\in \{1\}$, then it means that $x=1$ or $x=null$.

This same problem also happened while defining subsets, but then rather than defining what is a subset I ended up defining what is not and so avoided using $x\in \emptyset$

A is not subset of B if there is a x such that $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$, otherwise A is subset of B.

Comment: The statement $x \in \emptyset$ is always false, so "$x \in \{1\} \lor x \in \emptyset$" is equivalent to the statement "$x \in \{1\}$".

Comment: Then how would we define union of two empty sets or an empty set and a non-empty set. I mean the definition is so, that it don't avoids the term $x\in \emptyset$

Comment: I don't see what the problem is: "$x\in\{1\}\vee x\in\emptyset$" is exactly equivalent to "$x\in\{1\}$," or "$x=1$" if you prefer. Nothing surprising happens with the emptyset here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take the proposition again:

$A\cup B=\{x:x\in A\lor x\in B\}$

It means that **$\mathbf A$ union $\mathbf B$ is a set, which only has all the element(s) which belong to $\mathbf A$ or to $\mathbf B$.**
This one clearly defines the case when only one of the set is empty. For example, if $A$ is empty and $B=\{1\}$ then no element belongs to $A$, but $1$ belongs to $A$ or to $B$, so $1$ belongs to their union.

Now, if both are empty then we can say that no element belongs to $A$ or to $B$. If we assume that still $A\cup B$ has element(s), then it clearly becomes case of contradiction. That leaves us with only one option, that is $A \cup B$ is empty set. Now, if the union is empty set does it follow the second condition that it *only has all the element(s) which belong to $\mathit A$ or to $\mathit B$*. This was a little surprise to me since it does follow that condition, we can see it from [the article on vacuous truth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%20and%20logic%2C%20a,cell%20phones%20in%20the%20room.).

That means that the element of an empty set do have all property including the fact that it belongs to $A$ or $B$. This is because in first place there is no element of an empty set.

If we see the term $x\in \emptyset$, it has always truth value false. So, no it isn't defined, and neither do we need to define it.

$A=\{x \mid ...\}$, here '$A$ is a set which only has all the element(s)  such that the element(s) have ...' is the interpretation I used above. This interpretation needs a person to know about [vacuous truth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%20and%20logic%2C%20a,cell%20phones%20in%20the%20room.), to allow for $A$ to be empty set. However, there is another interpretation that ' $A$ is a set, and an element belongs to this set if and only if the element has ....'. This makes the interpretation of union as '**$\mathbf A$ union $\mathbf B$ is a set, and an element belongs to this set if and only if the element belongs to $\mathbf A$ or to $\mathbf B$**' , and we don't need a person to know about vacuous truth.

It's no doubt that the similar problem also occured to me while defining subsets. However what I did to define subsets is kind of interesting, because now I have realised that I can similarly define what is union by simply defining which element it should not contain rather than defining which element it should contain as:

**$\mathbf A$ union $\mathbf B$ is a set which don't has an element which don't belong to both $\mathbf A$ and to $\mathbf B$.**

Acknowledgement: I want to acknowledge [the answer by Eric Towers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3904106/829475), it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> **Naturally**

It's all very natural. Imagine you have two bags $A$ and $B$ (emptiness doesn't matter) containing (if not empty) colorful balls. And you take a third bag $C$ to collect all distinct balls they have (union of other two bags).

- If neither of them is empty there is no "problem" with doing this task $(C=A\cup B)$.
- If one of them is empty $($say, $A=\emptyset)$, then naturally, the third bag will contain all elements of the non-empty bag $(C = B)$ since there is no element in $A$ to include in $C$.
- If both are empty $(A=B=\emptyset)$, then the third bag will also be empty since there is no ball to "collect" at all $(C = \emptyset)$.

Stemming from the above statements we come to the following

> **Definition**

- If $A,B \neq \emptyset$, then $\boxed{A\cup B = \{x \mid x \in A \text{ or } x \in B \text{ or both}\}}$
- (WLOG) If $A =\emptyset \neq B$, then $\boxed{A \cup B = B}$
- If $A=B=\emptyset$, then $\boxed{A\cup B = \emptyset}$

*(This definition can be gathered to a more compact form, but this form seems to solve the problems that OP is asking)*

---

> **Conclusion**

Therefore, there is no need to think of any non-existent object for $x \in  \{1\}$ which is equivalent to $x \in \{1\}\cup \emptyset$, and there is no $x$ such that $x \in \{~\}$ (the empty set is indeed empty).

Comment: "$x$ prefers to have a value rather than being non-existent": what does this mean? I honestly can't parse this. There either exists such an $x$ or there does not. $x$ has no preference in the matter.

Comment: @Navneet You can define such value stemming from your situation: You may define $$x\in \emptyset \implies x = \text{NULL}$$ or something similar if needed. But if you see the notation $\emptyset$ as $\{~\}$, it makes almost no sense. So, I do not recommend messing things up.

Comment: @VIVID Undefining the term leaves the union of two set undefined, until we define union for non-empty sets different and empty sets different, as you did in your answer. So, should I assume you are saying that define union of two sets differently to avoid paradox?

Comment: I downvoted due to the nonsense involving null in the comment.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft And I also told that I do not recommend that and that makes no sense.  Null was just to imagine that it would lead to messing everything up. I don't think I did something that deserves a downvote...

Comment: @Navneet No. I do not remember that I ever told the union of sets involving empty and non-empty sets differ. Please, see the addition if it satisfies your questions.

Comment: @VIVID I am talking about a formal mathematical definition. I know the thing you told is right, but how would I define union is a big problem.

Comment: @Navneet Aren't you still convinced that $\{1\}\cup \emptyset = \{1\}$?

Comment: @VIVID I am definitely convinced, as I said in my comment. The thing you are saying is completely right.

Comment: @Navneet Ok, see my (probably) last addition. It seems I kind of misunderstand you, sorry $\ddot \smile$

Comment: @VIVID It seems like you used a version of De Morgan's law to prove that, which is wrong since, you can't use an identity to define union when the identity itself includes union, you have to prove identity first which needs defining union. You can also make this an axiom rather than an identity, but I guess that will make things too much complicated. [De Morgan's law wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#:~:text=In%20propositional%20logic%20and%20Boolean,both%20valid%20rules%20of%20inference.&text=The%20rules%20allow%20the%20expression,of%20each%20other%20via%20negation.)

Comment: @Navneet I take my **"Naturally"** section as (both natural and formal) definition of the union of sets since there was nothing informal.

Answer (score 1):

"Which means x is 1 or there is no element as x."

Not quite.  It means either $x \in \{1\}$ or $x \in \varnothing$ or both.  (The trailing "or both" resolves [an ambiguity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95624/use-of-or-inclusive-or-exclusive) in English.  If we agree that we are using "or" to represent [logical disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction), the "or both" can be omitted and we choose to do so subsequently)  The clause $x \in \{1\}$ is only true when $x = 1$ and is false otherwise.  The clause $x \in \varnothing$ is always false.  Therefore, the only $x$ for which $x \in \{1\}$ or $x \in \varnothing$ is $x = 1$.

The clause "$x \in \varnothing$" does not mean "there is no element as $x$" when it is used as a logical proposition.  It means "has the [truth value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_value) true when $x$ is such that $x \in \varnothing$ and has the truth value false when $x$ is such that $x \not \in \varnothing$".  Since always $x \not \in \varnothing$, this clause always has the truth value false.

---

A statement may have a truth value.  The statement "$1 = 1$" is always true.  The statement "$x = 1$" is only true when $x$ has the value $1$.

Consider the statement "$x \in \{1\}$".  This clause can be satisfied (that is, has the truth value "true") when $x = 1$.    If $x$ has any other value, the statement is false.  If $x$ does not have a definite value, the statement does not have a truth value.

Consider the statement "$x \in \varnothing$", which is literally "$x$ is an element of the empty set".  There is no value $x$ can have that makes the statement true.  The statement is always false.

It is important to treat both of these clauses similarly.  Membership in a set is the same thing for all sets.  There is not a special, different version of membership for the empty set.  When you write "$x$ is 1", you are expressing a different clause than when you write "there is no element as $x$".  This means the clause you intend for one set membership is different from the clause you intend for the other.  This is incorrect -- both clauses must have the same structure.

The clause $A \vee B$, where $A$ and $B$ are clauses with truth values, is true when either $A$ or $B$ is true and is false when both $A$ and $B$ are false.

Now let us study the expression
$$  (x \in \{1\}) \vee (x \in \varnothing)  \text{,}  $$
defining the set $U = \{1\} \cup \varnothing$.  When $x = 1$, this expression is
$$  \text{True} \vee \text{False}  \text{,}  $$
which is true.  So $1 \in U$.  When $x$ has any other value, this expression is
$$  \text{False} \vee \text{False}  \text{,}  $$
which is false.  Consequently, $U = \{1\}$.

One can also phrase this in terms of [witnesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witness_(mathematics)).  To do so , we make a slight change -- we introduce existential statements, having the form "there exists (variable) such that (proposition) [is true]".  (The "is true" is optional since it is assumed by default that a simple assertion is claiming a truth value of true.)  For example, there is an $x$ such that $x$ is even.  The assignment $x = 2$ satisfies this existential statement, so $2$ is a witness to the truth of the statement.

This notion of witness is, I think, a way to see what you want to see.  The clause "there is no element as $x$" is a statement about existence and we are able to handle such statements in logic.

The statement "there exists an $x$ such that $x \in \{1\} \cup \varnothing$" has a witness : $1$.  So this statement is true.

The statement "there exists an $x$ such that $x \in \varnothing \cup \varnothing$" has no witness, so this statement is false.  There is no thing that is an element of $\varnothing \cup \varnothing$, a property held exclusively by the empty set.  So "$\varnothing \cup \varnothing$" is just another way to write the empty set.

Comment: I don't understand the last part about truth value, since, I am in standard 11 and have not studied formal logic. If you can explain it a little more, I will be really thankful to you.

Comment: @Navneet : I observe that there is a convenient link, "truth value" to an extensive article explaining truth values.

Comment: I read that wiki page, and I came to understand that the truth value is either true or false based on truth of statement. But, I still don't understand what the last paragraph wants to convey. $x\in \emptyset$ has the truth value true when x is such that $x\in \emptyset$ and has the truth value false when $x\notin \emptyset$, that is obvious but at first we need to define what we mean by $x\in \emptyset$ or $x\notin \emptyset$. You said that the clause doesn't mean that, then what does it mean?

Comment: Saying that this clause always has the truth value false means x can't belong to an empty set, but then how would we define union of two sets, in which either of them or both are empty set.

Comment: @Navneet: Please be patient. People may live in a different time zone than you, they may have jobs, or they may simply have other things to do. And if someone doesn't feel like expanding more in the comments, it's their absolute right to do so.

Comment: @Navneet : More words added.